# Difference between getElementById and createElement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using javascript from few days. And i am confusing between getElementById and createElement.

**THANKS IN ADVANCE**

Comment: Also, the method names are pretty self explanatory...

Comment: Not a real question, unless you really can't tell that one function gets an element by its id and the other one creates an element. I don't remember which one does what though, I'm confused by the missing spaces and capital letters

Comment: What's the difference between transversing DOM elements and creating new ones? All possible differences, except that you're working with DOM elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is that `getElementById` will get an element from the DOM by it's ID attribute, and `createElement` will create an entirely new DOM element.

Let's say you had a page with the following HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>Hello, World!</div>
    <div id="message">What a nice day!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And then you had some JavaScript code like so:

```
document.getElementById("message")
```

You will retrieve the `<div>` element that has an `id` attribute of `"message"`.

Now, let's say you wanted to add a new element to your HTML page, then you'd use the `createElement` function.

```
var newEl = document.createElement("div")
```

Of course, from the example, we are also storing the new element in a variable called `newEl`.

Now, to actually append the new element, we'd have to call `appendChild` on any DOM element. For the sake of simplicity, we're going to simply append to the `<body>` tag.

```
document.body.appendChild(newEl)
```

Now, your page should (at least in the mind of the browser) look like so:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>Hello, World!</div>
    <div id="message">What a nice day!</div>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

They are two different things

**getElementById** selects an element using their id which is present in your DOM

But

**createElement** creates a new Element which can be inserted into the DOM